# Why does the construction of a 'CImage' (GDI+) make the programm crash?

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+

I wanted to try using the class CImage, which comes from GDI+, to load an image and draw it at some place in my Graphical User Interface.

However, the programm crashes as soon as I call CImage's constructor, it seems, displaying the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7757D968 (ntdll.dll) in myProgramm.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014
```

If I choose to break the programm after the exception, I can see that the cursor, which indicate the current called function, is pointing some CImage's method :

```
CImage::CInitGDIPlus::IncreaseCImageCount()
```

That's a reason why I was supposing GDI+ initialization could be the cause of the problem. So I have written a sample to possibly identify the problem, trying whether to initialize GDI+ or not.

```
// main.cpp
// (Do not forget to link gdiplus.lib and activate "Use MFC in a shared DLL")

#include <afxwin.h> 
#include <afxdockablepane.h> // CImage seems to be unknown without this include. (My actual program uses it anyway.)
#include <Gdiplus.h>

void testWithoutGdipInititalization()
{
        CImage image ; // The programm seems to crash here, at the construction of the image...
}; // ...And not here, at the destruction of the image

void testWithGdipInititalization()
{
    // Initialize GDI+.
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdipStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdipToken ;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdipToken, &gdipStartupInput, NULL);

    {
        CImage image ; // The programm seems to crash here, at the construction of the image...
    } // ...And not here, at the destruction of the image

    // Close Gdiplus
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdipToken); 
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool withInitialization = true ;

    if(withInitialization)
        testWithGdipInititalization();
    else
        testWithoutGdipInititalization();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

...And both fail the same way.

Does someboy know what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: *"`// The programm seems to crash here`"* - Set up Visual Studio to break when a Win32 exception is **thrown**, and you no longer have to guess, where exactly the exception is raised.

Comment: If you are using CImage, I don't think is necessary to initialize gdiplus ... try without Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdipStartupInput ... and so on.

Comment: Besides, you are passing an uninitialized `GdiplusStartupInput` structure to `GdiplusStartup`. And you are passing `NULL` for the *output* parameter, which is only allowed, if you set *SuppressBackgroundThread* of the [GdiplusStartupInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534067.aspx) structure to `FALSE`. This [mcve] exhibits undefined behavior, and cannot be used to verify anything.

Comment: @IInspectable `Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput` has default constructor, it doesn't need initialization unless it's a `C` program with `GdiplusStartupInput` struct. I couldn't duplicate this error.

Comment: By the way, header file for `CImage` is `<atlimage.h>`, it should tell you that in MSDN documentation. If making a console program, you can use ATL components without adding MFC window support. Otherwise just make a regular MFC program with the project wizard.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I keep forgetting, that GDI+ is the odd one out, that exposes a C++ interface. Thank you for pointing that out.